# Need to use opengl in combination with View

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am new in android. I need to use opengl in combination with View Class to draw something. How to do this. plz give me any hints or suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

You also have the option to combine "normal" android views (Button, ImageView, etc) in a layout with a GlSurfaceView. (i.e. FrameLayout)

By doing so you can combine normal android UI with openGL, you can also make a composite view where the openGL view is just part of the layout.

This is the way ads are usually displayed overlaying 3D aplications.

Be aware that this technique can produce quite weird results in low end devices when dealing with tranasparency.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanta GlSurfaceView. It's a View that allows you to use Opengl to draw to it.

Put it in a layout file for your app

```
<GLSurfaceView id="@+id/myView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Then in your code

```
((GLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.myView)).setRenderer(new GlSurfaceView.Renderer() {
    public void onSurfaceCreated(...)...
    public void onSurfaceChanged(...)...
    public void onDraw(GL10 gl)...
});
((GLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.myView)).setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
```

And then you draw in your onDraw with your gl calls.

This is the super-quick start answer to your question, if you drop the surfaceview in framelayout and know what your drawing it's pretty quick to get a basic setup running.

Comment: I it mean that i wish to use 2d in combination with 3d.

Comment: well then you typically have 2 projections, one ortho and one perspective. You then just change the projection matrix mid-frame and start drawing 2d.

Comment: Or you can use the regular view hierchy of android to render to a texture, and then render in opengl.

There is limited "layering" of opengl and regular views allowed too, but it's very limited.