# Add custom Animation done in OpenGL to Activities

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es

I have got an animation developed using OpenGL in Android,

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

Actually the animation in the above link, animates the images applying page curl animation. I wish to apply it to activities instead.

I wish to implement this animation as a transition between 2 activities,
Could u suggest me, how i should proceed with it.

Comment: Have a look at these -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449824/need-to-use-opengl-in-combination-with-view
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839591/how-does-opengl-es-for-android-work
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288113/where-is-the-documentation-for-opengl-es-2-0-on-android