# How does OpenGL ES for android work?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opengl-es

I am doing a project where I'm creating my own 3D graphics using android studio.

I have so far created a rotating sphere using a perspective projection and my own classes of shapes that contain the shapes vertices and faces. Each face is drawn as a triangle to a bitmap, which an ImageView updates itself with.

However the program is slow as I guess all the calculations run in software and not hardware.

I have now seen that I can use OpenGL ES to use hardware to perform the calculations needed, **however I am not sure if OpenGL will perform all the transformation calculations for me.** I do not want this as it would defy the point of my project.

I want to know if I can use my own code to perform the perspective projection, **or if OpenGL turns 3D coordinates into 2D for me?** Or alternatively if I can use OpenGL 2D to render my already rasterised triangles?

Furthermore is there a way to get my algorithms to run on hardware to speed them up? And can you chose how many of OpenGL's algorithms you use?

Comment: I think you should check out some beginner opengl-es tutorial for android to get an overall understanding what runs on the gpu and which parts does opengl for you.

Comment: Start here https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html